# Puppet - How to install git 1.8.x which isn't in default packages

Tags: puppet, git, apt, gitlab

How would you automate the installation of a specific version of git using puppet?

`apt-get update && apt-get install git-core` on my 12.04 ubuntu server results in git version 1.7.9.
I must have 1.7.10 or newer.

There are two options that I can see.
1. Add the ppa
2. Install git from source

I think adding a ppa would be easier that compiling from source, so that is what I am attempting.

I've tried using the [puppetlabs/apt module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) to install the git-core ppa, yet my git version is still 1.7.9 after the puppet run.

```
root@gitlab:~# puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules
├── puppetlabs-apt (v1.2.0)
├── puppetlabs-git (v0.0.3)
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.1.0)
└── ruby (???)


root@gitlab:~# cat /etc/puppet/manifests/git.pp  

class { 'apt': }
apt::ppa { 'ppa:git-core/ppa': 
  before => Exec['apt-get update'],

}

exec{'apt-get update':
  path => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
}

package {'git-core':
   ensure => latest,
   require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

root@gitlab:~# puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/git.pp --verbose
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Applying configuration version '1379214336'
Notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-get update]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: Finished catalog run in 5.80 seconds
root@gitlab:~# git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
```

Answer (score 1):

`git-core` isn't the package in that PPA - you want `git` instead (and probably to remove `git-core` from the Ubuntu repo).

Answer (score 0):

As Shane mentioned you should use `git` instead of `git-core` in the package definition.

Also there is no need to create the `Exec['apt-get update']` dependency, because the module is already taking care of that.

Code from the module:

```
exec { "add-apt-repository-${name}":
  ...
  notify    => Exec['apt_update'],
  ...
}
```

So if you want to keep git up to date all the time you should do something like that:

```
class {'ntp': always_apt_update => true, }
```

and

```
package {'git':
 ensure => latest,
 require => Apt::Ppa['ppa:git-core/ppa'],
}
```